# How to add a new group but teacher has to come from a list

Tags: python, django

I want to add a new group but for the teacher they have to choose from a list that is in the table Teacher because it has a relation with Groups.
**tables**: Teacher, Group
**Relation:** Teacher **1 to many** Group

models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Leraren, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.teacher)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='name', max_length=100)

class GroupForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='name', max_length=100)
    teacher = # choose from list of teachers that are in the db Teachers #
```

Comment: When you try to choose from the list in the db, what happens? what goes wrong? what do you expect?

Comment: form action is post and name of list is teacher. What do I have to write in forms.py to get that post name variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the Form as a `ModelForm` for `Group`, theres no need to do this all manually

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew that!